# Why isn't variable value updating?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
count = 0
number = count

while count < 10:
    print number
    count = count + 1
```

The result is not what i was expecting at all. It prints out 10 `0`.

I'm completely baffled as to why the value of `number` stays at zero? Why isn't it updating as `count` updates?

Comment: You need to update the value of `number` inside your loop.

Comment: Intro to Python names: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 6):

In Python, `int` objects are **immutable**; you cannot change their value. All you can do is *rebind* a name to a new integer object. Both `count` and `number` are just references to `int` objects here.

The expression `count + 1` does not alter `count`. It returns a *different* `int` object and rebinds `count` to now reference that new value.

All this means that `number` is still referencing `0`; it was never rebound. It certainly won't follow what happened to `count`.

Compare this to *mutable* objects, where you *can* change the value itself. A list object for example, is mutable in that you can change what its indices are bound to. Two names can then reference that list object and any changes are then visible through both references:

```
>>> foo = [1]
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar
[1]
>>> foo[0] = foo[0] + 1
>>> bar
[2]
```

Here I changed what was bound to index 0 *contained* in the list object, and the change is visible wether you look at `foo` or `bar`, both references to the same object. I never changed `foo` itself; I did not re-assign it to point to something else.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the value of `number` is not assigned inside the loop, but outside. There is no constant 'binding' between `number` and `count` but the value of `number` is just assigned once to `count` in your code.
Change it to the following and it will work.

```
count = 0
number = count

while count < 10:
    number = count
    print number
    count = count + 1
```